# Multiple or Single Git Repository

Tags: 8

Though this isn't about a Drupal issue specifically, it is specific to Drupal. I'm looking for community opinion on best practices for storing multiple versions of Drupal. 
In my case, I've got a production D7 site. And, I'm developing a Drupal 8 site.

I have pretty strong reasons for keeping those repositories separate. However, I've gotten pushback from management questioning why we can't just have one repository with a production branch for d7 and one for d8.

Comment: Because D7 and D8 are nothing alike and you wouldn't want any accidents :)
In all seriousness though, concept of branching out is saving your work while developing something new to be merged back in the future thus the repo should have the same codebase for branches. Also when you put ur d8 site live, you will possibly need to work on new features for it and end up chaining your branches.. 2 repos now is less headache later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

multiple repos is best option, I recommend even custom modules or themes (for Drupal 8) have individual repos that way you can better manage these and re-use them in other projects more efficiently. assuming your using composer for package management.